# What is the difference between Scaffold and MaterialApp in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two screens, where
 **First:** Listing of data from Firebase
 **Second:** Add data in that screen so I want to comeback to first screen,
 Everything working fine only there was a black screen when I go back. 
Now issue was gone, I have searched for how it works but its still not clear my concept about this, Can any one describe how it works?

**Before**:

```
return new MaterialApp(
      title: "AddEditNames ",
      home: new AddEditNameScreen(),
);
```

**After**: when i have replaced it  by

```
 return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 1.0),
      body: new AddEditNameScreen(),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        actions: <Widget>[
        ],
        title: new Text(
          "AddEditNames",
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
 );
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`MaterialApp` is the starting point of your app, it tells Flutter that you are going to use Material components and follow material design in your app.

`Scaffold` is used under `MaterialApp`, it gives you many basic functionalities, like `AppBar`, `BottomNavigationBar`, `Drawer`, `FloatingActionButton` etc.

So, this is how a typical app starts with.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: YourWidget(),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: In my flutter app I have used MaterialApp for all screens. so Would it affect the performance? @CopsOnRoad

Comment: @BalajiRamadoss There should be just one `MaterialApp` for the entire app unless you're going to do some wanky stuff.

Comment: If MaterialApp is already telling that we can use the Material Components like AppBar,etc., then why use Scaffold? and vice versa.

Answer (score 22):

`MaterialApp` is a widget that introduces a number of widgets (`Navigator`, `Theme` ) that are required to build a Material design app.

While `Scaffold` let you implement the material standard app widgets that most application has. Such as `AppBar`, `BottomAppBar`, `FloatingActionButton`, `BottomSheet`, `Drawer`, `Snackbar`.

The `Scaffold` is designed to be the single top-level container for a MaterialApp although it is not necessary to nest a `Scaffold`.

Also checkout official Flutter doc for [`MaterialApp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) and [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html).

Comment: when I had put  Navigator.of(mContext).pushNamed('/screen1')  in MaterialApp  its not working properly but when i put it in  Scaffold  it  works as it has to ,So my doubt it about how it behave to stack ?

Comment: Imo "The `Scaffold` is designed to be the single top-level container for a `MaterialApp` although it is not necessary to nest a Scaffold" sounds like a `MaterialApp` would normally only include a single `Scaffold`. Which is with multiple pages and a `Navigator` not the case.

Answer (score 4):

The Material app is the core component and a predefined class. We can use the Material app to create widgets to design applications in Flutter. The Material app has several properties. Some of them are title, home, theme, color, routes, etc.

Scaffold is also another class which can be used to design application. It provides us APIs such as snack bars, bottom sheets, app bar, floating action bar, etc. Scaffold provides us a framework to implement the visual layout structure of the application.

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter, `MaterialApp` serves as the root widget for creating material design-based applications. It introduces essential components like navigation and themes to the app. On the other hand, `Scaffold` is a key component within `MaterialApp` that provides a structural layout for your app's user interface.

Think of `Scaffold` as a platform that offers a foundation for building your app's interface. It includes various built-in features such as `AppBar`, `BottomNavigationBar`, `Drawer`, `FloatingActionButton`, `BottomSheet`, and more. These features help you establish a consistent visual structure and enhance the user experience.

Essentially, `MaterialApp` sets the overall theme and navigation for your app, while `Scaffold` provides a ready-to-use layout structure with pre-defined widgets. You can customize and extend `Scaffold` to create your desired app layout and functionality.

It's worth noting that the term '**Scaffold**' itself implies a platform-like structure. Additionally, I mentioned '**root**,' which refers to the top-most widget in the widget hierarchy, serving as the starting point of your app.

Similar to Google's design system `MaterialApp` & `Scaffold`, for Apple's design system, we have `CupertinoApp` & `CupertinoPageScaffold` in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

- MatarialApp() is a class that contains all Material design components(text, icon, textfield,..... It is use only one time in your app and it mean that you are going to use all materials design in your app.
- Scffold() is a class that have important widget such as Appbar, body, floatingActionButton,... In each screen have to return Scaffold() to use all those widget to disign your screen.
  MaterialApp() > Scaffold()

Answer (score 0):

This is old thread, but a good relevant subject...

Scaffolding goes back to the beginning of programming...  I used to scaffold before scaffold was a term.  When you program, over time, you quickly learn that you do a lot of the same repetitive tasks, or use the same common components or themes. It's called building consistency... Scaffolding is a fancy way of saying template.

In the context of flutter, a scaffold says that you want an application or page that will be displayed as a topbar, body, and bottombar.

Scaffolding takes a template and merges data from a source to create an end result.